# Wireless refuses to connect after waking up from suspend/sleep mode on XPSP3 on HP Mini 1101 netbook

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, sleep

(I've been trying things for a few months with no solution.  Since the day I got this netbook, got it up to speed with SP3 and Windows Update over and over, and with the proper drivers installed for its "Broadcom 802.11 b/g WLAN", I cannot figure this issue out.)

Most of the time, but not always, coming from standby, it has disconnected from the wireless router, and will never reconnect, until I reboot the computer (even rebooting the router and running "repair" on the wireless connection doesn't help.)  Yet, I don't believe it has powered down, because it accurately can refresh the list of wireless routers available in my area.  It just will never successfully connect--waits for a long time and then says it wasn't able.  What could be wrong?

Comment: Device Manager, open network adapter's properties and test with [Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r7eho.jpg) *unchecked*.

Comment: @Karan, thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't have that option.  Also, if it were stuck powered down, it wouldn't be able to refresh the network list, from my understanding, and also a Repair... should fix it, no?